# OpenLayers prevent DragPan from bottom of screen

Tags: openlayers, interaction, dragpan

My OpenLayers app runs on iPhones in full-screen.  Of course on recent models of iPhone, there is a system gesture of swiping up from the bottom of the screen to suspend the app (eg, to return to the iOS home screen, or to switch to another app).

In my OpenLayers app, this gesture is also recognised simultaneously by OpenLayers as a DragPan interaction.  This results in the map being panned every time the user wants to suspend the app, and then when they resume the app, the map extent is different to when they left it.

So I want to replace the standard DragPan interaction with a customised DragPan interaction that will do nothing if the user's drag (swipe) starts near the bottom of the map (ie, the bottom of the screen).

I believe that in order to do this, I should be able to use the `condition` property of the `DragPan` interaction to return `false` if the drag started at the bottom of the screen (eg, lets say within 10 pixels from the bottom of the map).  However, I can't figure out how to determine if the drag started within 10 pixels from the bottom of the map.

Below is the code that I have tried, but it does not work.  The `console.log(event.pixel)` line, outputs reasonable values that I would expect.  But even when less than 100, the map still moves with the DragPan.

(Note that I'm using 100 instead of 10 in the code for the sake of easier testing.  Note also that this is testing for a coordinate near the top of the view, not the bottom.  But one step at a time.)

How do I get the screen/view coordinates of where the DragPan event started or otherwise, how do I determine if the drag started within 10 pixels of the bottom of the map from within this `condition` function?

```
    map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
        if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragPan) {
            map.removeInteraction(interaction);
        }
    });
    map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.DragPan({
        condition: function (event) {
            console.log(event.pixel);
            return event.pixel[1] > 100;
        }
    }));
```

**UPDATE**:  I've found that even if I return `false`, the DragPan still continues to pan the map!  What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE 2 - FIXED**:  Doh!  I actually still had another DragPan interaction added to the map from some other parts of the code, and of course the other DragPan was still functioning.  I have now got it working correctly for ignoring DragPans initiated at the top of the map.  Once I get it working for the bottom of the map, I'll write up a proper answer.

**Remaining Question**:  How do I get the height of the map view, in pixels?  This is required so that I can compare it to the DragPan's pixels.  It appears as though the DragPan's pixel values have the origin at the top, so I have to use the difference between the the pixel-height of the view and the DragPan's pixel (y) value.

Comment: The height is `map.getSize()[1]`, or in an event you could use `event.frameState.size[1]`  You should also test the default contidtions otherwise you might break other interactions which rely on modifier keys (e.g. rotate) https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-c9wd4g?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I'll write up an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Based in part on the comment from @Mike here's how I got it to work correctly:

```
function dragPanExcludingHomeBar() {
    return new ol.interaction.DragPan({
        condition: function (event) {
            return event.frameState.size[1] - event.pixel[1] > 100;
        },
   });
}


map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragPan) {
        map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    }
});

map.addInteraction(dragPanExcludingHomeBar());
```